# System wide keyboard layout

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to change the keyboard layout of the whole system to another layout? I am using a bunch of window managers and I don't want to have to setup the layout for every one.

I am using a QWERTY keyboard with a programmer DVORAK overlay.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. I myself am a *[Dvorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard_layout)* user. Here is how:

1. Log in to one of your window managers. Switch to *Dvorak*. Dump the layout with this command:

   ```
   xmodmap -pke>dvorak.map
   ```
2. Load the *dvorak.map* file in your X init file, `~/.xinitrc`

   ```
   xmodmap /path/to/dvorak.map
   ```

Comment: I can't get it to work, I tried exactly what you described but nothing happened, and then I tried it in the TTY and I got `xmodmap: unable to open display ''`

Comment: you cannot use xmodmap in a tty. you should use it in a terminal emulator, like gnome-terminal.